# Do I need On Prem AD if using using Azure Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, windows-domain, azure-activedirectory

I work for a small company and we are at the point where we need to set up a domain and centrally manage resources. My question is if I could set up Azure Active Directory and manage our resources just like a local instance of AD and skip the local AD. Thanks!

Comment: I think the question is getting into the specifics of what you want to do. check here for common comparision: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-compare-azure-ad-to-ad Also note that UDP traffic (and thus LDAP) cannot usually traverse the link between on-prem and in-cloud, so all client technologies will need to have a working client for AAD.

Comment: Hey Frank, thank you for your comment and link.  Cheers!